# Visual Studio Compiler Configuration Options

Tags: c++

I have recently inherited an old c++ project built in visual studio 2003 that consists of a lot of code that looks like this:

```
for(int i=7;i<40;i++)
    title[i-7]=temp_title[i];
for(i=33;i<80;i++)
    title[i] = ' ';
```

However, since I do not have VS2003, I installed 2008 and now I am running into a lot of compilation errors due to i being an undeclared identifier since its out of scope.  I am a complete novice to visual studio, how do I configure my project so it uses whatever compatible c++ compiler for 2003 so I can build the project and see what the heck its supposed to do.

@Kirill V. Lyadvinsky

Yes, I do plan to fix the code, however, I'd like to have a base version that I can use to test against in case I mess something up since the person who wrote this is now retired (thankfully)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an option [/Zc:forScope (Force Conformance in for Loop Scope)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984). Switch it off as in the picture below. But I'd strongly recommend to fix the code so it will be conformant with current C++ Standard.

[image: image:200]

Answer (score 1):

`/Zc:forscope-` is what you seem to be looking for.